# Python: How do I syntax data scraping from xlsx file?

Tags: python, pep8

Currently I am scraping some data from xlsx file. My code works, but looks like a mess - at least for me.
So I am unsure if my code is ok according to PEP8.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
[...]
        for row in sheet.iter_rows():
            id = row[0].value
            name = row[1].value
            second_name = row[2].value
            # ignore the following
            # middle_name = row[3].value
            city = row[4].value
            address = row[5].value
            field_x = row[7].value
            field_y = row[10].value
            some_function_to_save_to_database(id, name, second_name, ...)
```

etc. (Please note that for some of those values I do extra-validation etc).
So it works but it feels a bit "clunky". Obviously I could pass them directly to function, making it `some_function_to_save_to_database(row[0].value, row[1].value, ...)`, but is it any better? Feels like I lose readability a lot in this one.

So my question is as follows: Is it good approach or should I map those fields field names to row order? What is proper way to style this kind of scraping?

Comment: Had you run `pylint` against your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not violate PEP8. However, it's a little cumbersome. And it's not easy to maintain if the data changed. Maybe you can try:

```py
DATA_INDEX_MAP = {
    'id' : 0,
    'name' : 1,
    'second_name' : 2,
    'city' : 4,
    'address' : 5,
    'field_x' : 7,
    'field_y' : 10
}

def get_data_from_row(row):
    return {key:row[DATA_INDEX_MAP[key]].value for key in DATA_INDEX_MAP}

for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    data = get_data_from_row(row)
    some_function_to_save_to_database(**data)
```

Then what you need to do is just to modify `DATA_INDEX_MAP`.

Answer (score 0):

A lighter alternative to the `dict` in [LiuChang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630198/1126841):

```
from operator import itemgetter

get_data = itemgetter(0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10)
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    data = [x.value for x in get_data(row)]
    some_function_to_save_to_database(*data))
```